# Return records from a database if record doesnt exist in both tables? PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a bit of an issue I cant seem to figure out with google searching alone!

Im trying to return all users from my table excluding the currently logged in session user, I do that with...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM users 
    WHERE user_id <> ? 
    AND credits_offered <= credits_bank');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have another table however named `user_friendships` in this table there is 3 columns,

`id | user_id | user_followed_id`

In my query, Id like to somehow add a `where` clause saying that if any of the users returned, exist in the `user_followed_id` column of user friendships table then dont return them as a result, does this make sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either `LEFT JOIN` the friendships, add `WHERE friendships.somenonnullablecolumn IS NULL`, or alternatively, use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN user_friendships uf ON u.user_id = uf.user_followed_id
WHERE u.user_id <> ? 
   AND u.credits_offered <= credits_bank
   AND uf.user_followed_id IS NULL
```

Comment: @Liam -- np, glad I could help.